# How to prove that if two sets $X$, $Y$ are disjoint, then $X\setminus Y=X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would you prove that:

$$(A \cap B = \emptyset) \Rightarrow ((A \setminus B)=A)?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the definitions, 
\[ A \cap B:= \{ x\in A \wedge x\in B\}\]

\[ A\setminus B := \{x\in A \wedge x\not\in B\} \]

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $A\setminus B\subseteq A$, so we need to show that $A\subseteq A\setminus B$. Suppose that $a\in A$ is an arbitrary element, our assumption is that $A\cap B=\varnothing$, so $a\notin B$.

What can you conclude next which is relevant to the proof?